# Не работает Атрибут hashtags:twitter в yandex share

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Здравствуйте, уважаемые пользователи Stackoverflow.com. При шаринге в твиттер не появляются хэштеги, которые мне нужны. При этом атрибут hashtags:twitter есть в разметке, скрипт ya share подключен.

Прилагаю код:

```
<script src="https://yastatic.net/share2/share.js" async="async">
<p style="text-align: center;"
class="ya-share2"
data-counter=""
data-services="pocket,facebook,gplus,vkontakte,odnoklassniki,twitter"
hashtags:twitter="рецепты,кулинария,пошагово,хорошая,еда">
</p>
```

Спасибо за внимание!

Answer (score 0):

```
data-hashtags:twitter="рецепты,кулинария,пошагово,хорошая,еда"
```